# Is it possible to add client credentials using the Dart http library?

Tags: dart

The `HttpClient` class in `dart:io` enables you to add credentials to client requests, like so:

```
var client = new HttpClient()
  ..addCredentials( ...creds... );
```

The problem is that I need multipart file upload support, and this has proven extremely difficult to do using `dart:io`. The `http` library is *much* better for this.

The problem is that, as far as I can tell, it is not possible to add credentials to a client request in the `http` library. If I'm wrong and there is, in fact, a way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the `authorization` header to the multipart request. For Basic authentication :

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);

final auth = CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(UTF8.encode("$username:$password"));
request.headers['authorization'] = "Basic $auth";

//....
```

Comment: I am using Dart 1.15 and converting to Base64 did change. One does not need the Crypto package anymore but can use 'dart:convert' for it: `final auth = BASE64.encode(UTF8.encode("${username}:${password}"));`

Answer (score 1):

BASE64 and UTF8 are now themselves deprecated (though actually renamed to lower case). Use...

```
import 'dart:convert';

String token = "Basic " + base64.encode(utf8.encode("${username}:${password}"));
```